# Setting up basic relationship with Fetch Requests

Tags: core-data, entity-relationship, nsfetchrequest

I am wanting to set up a basic relationship with two entities in Core Data, but the relationship is either not saving, or is not working properly and I'm not sure why.

The two entities are `Character` and `Avatar`, its a one-to-one relationship.  A character can have 1 avatar.  Technically, it should be a "one avatar can be owned by many characters", but I'll deal with that later.

*I want to add characters and assign them an avatar.*

There are already 10 avatars in Core Data and 1 character, both of which I've verified via the Terminal and SQLite.

The problem is, I'm having troubling "finding an avatar by a name and then saving the relationship to a character".

So far,

I set up a fetch request called: "frqAvatarWithName" where the Predicate has the following structure:

[quote]

> name == $AVATAR_NAME

[/quote]

This is so: I can find an avatar with a certain name; and then I can create a relationship with a character.

**Issue 1:** It gets to execute the query but then never displays how many records there are.

I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in debug mode and I have traced it back to the fetch request template handling -- so, this must be in error or I have done it wrong.

**Issue 2:** I am not sure if I am even setting up this "basic" relationship up properly.

[code]

```
// This code is meant to find an avatar with a certain name and then save the relationship
// between a character and said avatar.
// This is my app delegate file for the moment
// All the files are present, and I have deleted/recreated the app various times
-(void)characterMaker
{
    NSLog(@"Inside characterMaker...");
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [self managedObjectModel];

    // Find an avatar with a specific name
    NSString *nameToFind = @"avt_player_1";


    // Use a Fetch request template
    NSDictionary *subs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nameToFind, @"AVATAR_NAME", nil];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [model fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"frqAvatarWithName" 
                                              substitutionVariables:subs];


    // Set the entity to use
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Avatar"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];


    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Execute the query (it never even reaches this point)
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        // Handle the error
        NSLog(@"Error -- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        abort();
    }

    NSLog(@"Found %@ records", [fetchedObjects count]);

// Print out avatar names
    for (Avatar *a in fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Name = %@", [a valueForKey:@"name"]);
    }

    // This is where I would use `a` and store it in a character entity, and thus create the relationship
```

[/code]

Comment: Clarification: Which exact line produces the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this and did the whole project with the FMDatabase project and SQLite; I've been able to resolve the problem this way.

Thread closed.